# Sessions and login to site by cURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to login to some page by cURL in php. 
I have this script :

```
$cookie_file = 'cookies.txt';
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.xxx.pl/index.php?act=ws&sub=login');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login=aaa&pass=bbb');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT    5.0)");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.xxx.pl/index.php');
//curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
//curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$cookie_file);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$cookie_file);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

When i run it the script log me in (i see new date in databse inserting on login) but when I open a site http://www.xxx.pl/ i am not loged. 
I think problem is about sessions. But i dont know how to resolve it.

Comment: What do you mean, "when I open the site"?  In a browser?  Future curl calls?

Comment: Yes , in browser. First I run the script. Next i open a site where i need to be loged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting session with cURL and capturing cookie data doesn't mean that session will be shared between your app and browser.

If you run script from same domain you need to:

- Parse cookie data captured by cURL
- use PHP's setcookie() function to return same cookie data to your browser.

After performing these steps browser will send cookies back to the server which initiated session.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zend_Http class and Zend_http_CookieJar (parts of the Zend Framework)
See here :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.http.cookies.html

> In most cases, there is no need to directly instantiate a Zend_Http_CookieJar object. If you want to attach a new cookie jar to your Zend_Http_Client object, just call the Zend_Http_Client->setCookieJar() method, and a new, empty cookie jar will be attached to your client. You could later get this cookie jar using Zend_Http_Client->getCookieJar().